# .npmignore not ignoring index.ts file when publishing

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install, npm-publish

I'm creating an Angular2 component library I'm publishing to npm.  I'm using index.ts as my barrel file throughout the source code.  I've included *.ts in my .npmignore file, however, index.ts is getting included in the code published to npm.  When I install the component in my consuming Angular2 project, index.ts is included in the code installed in node_modules folder.  Having index.ts throughout the npm installed library is preventing the primary application from building because index.ts is not in the root folder.  Surprisingly, all my other .ts files are being excluded in the npm install.

Here's my .npmignore file:

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
Thumbs.db
.DS_Store
.idea
.vscode
*.ts
**/*.ts
**/index.ts
!*.d.ts
.gitignore
.npmignore
license-banner.txt
tsconfig.json
tsconfig.publish.json
```

Everthing is getting ignored except index.ts.

I have to manually go in and delete every index.ts file then everything works as expected.

What am I missing that's causing index.ts to be included?

**I'm using npm version 3.9.6.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `**/index.ts` means that you want to ignore every `index.ts` file in every sub directories, not the root one. remove `**/` to fix this. anyways, `*.ts` should ignore `index.ts`...

Comment: thanks for response.  I originally had just *.ts and index.ts was still being included.  **/index.ts was an attempt to do a global exclude.  Every index.ts in all sub-directories are being included.  Grasping @ straws...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and trial and error, I discovered I needed to add an output directory for compiling my TS code into JS and typescript type information (.d.ts) files.  Once the generated code was in a separate folder (in this case /lib), my implementation changed to import from my lib folder.  All of my .ts files remained in the src folder.

My projects that have installed the library are now compiling as expected.  Bottom line is to make sure your generated code (JS and .d.ts files) are in a separate folder from your source code.  Seems obvious now.